# User login and Django OTP

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, one-time-password

I want the user to login using three fields, username, password and OTP ONLY.

Here is my **.html file**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% block head %}
    <title>HomePage</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div style='width:500px;margin:0 auto;' class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <form method="POST" class="form">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% bootstrap_form form %}
                    {% buttons %}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                    {% endbuttons %}
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the **browser** view of the .html file

[image]

I want to remove Otp Device and Otp Challenge as they are unnecessary for my case.

Here is my **models.py** file

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class ProjectUser(AbstractUser):
    # add additional fields in here

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Here is my urls.py file

```
from django_otp.forms import OTPAuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

urlpatterns = [

    path('user_login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name="accounts_app/user_login.html",
                                         authentication_form=OTPAuthenticationForm), name='user_login'), ]
```

Here is the [reference](https://django-otp-official.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auth.html#django_otp.decorators.otp_required) I used

Comment: As described in the documentation, you don't need to display those fields in your template, so instead of using `{% bootstrap_form form %}` just render the fields you need yourself. Or subclass `OTPAuthenticationForm` and change the widgets for these two fields to be `HiddenInput` widgets.

Comment: @dirkgroten I do want to use *bootstrap_form* therefore I rather choose the subclass method, Can you kindly show how to do that ?

Comment: you can use `{% bootstrap_field <field> %}` for each of the fields you want to show, that's usually how you customise your form rendering. But if you prefer to change the form fields' widgets, just subclass the form and set `otp_device = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)` and same for `otp_challenge`.

Comment: @dirkgroten can you please provide a full answer below so I can mark it :) Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

The straight forward way is to Subclass `OTPAuthenticationForm` to replace the form fields used for `otp_device` and `otp_challenge` by using the `HiddenInput` widget. In your app folder, create a new python file called `forms.py` and add the following

```
from django_otp.forms import OTPAuthenticationForm
from django import forms

class SimpleOTPAuthenticationForm(OTPAuthenticationForm):
    otp_device = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    otp_challenge = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

In your `urls.py` file inside your app, add the `import` and replace the `LoginView` with the following

```
from .forms import SimpleOTPAuthenticationForm

path('user_login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name="accounts_app/user_login.html",
                                      authentication_form=SimpleOTPAuthenticationForm), name='user_login'),
```

---

**Solution 2:**

Alternative option but requires more styling to fit the bootstrap form warning and other features. Start with using the following

Only display the fields you want in your template: Since `otp_device` and `otp_challenge` are not required, you can just leave them out. Use `{% bootstrap_field form.<field> %}` for each of the fields you want to display instead of `{% bootstrap_form form %}`. See [here](https://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templatetags.html#bootstrap3.templatetags.bootstrap3.bootstrap_field) for all the options to customise the rendering of each field. Errors for each field can be displayed with `{{ form.errors.<field> }}` but you have to style them yourself.

In your case

```
{% bootstrap_field form.username %}
{% bootstrap_field form.password %}
{% bootstrap_field form.otp_token %}
```

Comment: For option number one, where is the <field> parameter defined ?                      `{% bootstrap_field form.username %}`
 and                     `{% bootstrap_field form.password %}` works, but where is labels for the fields `username` and `password` in this case located ?

Comment: labels are displayed by default. You can customise a lot (see the docs, I added them to my answer)